# Button border thickness from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, border, styling

I am very new to wpf, and right now I am working with buttons, and so I want to change buttons border thickness, but from code behind not in XAML, and what I did was next:

```
var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#83D744");
btn0.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent; // This is applied to button
       btn0.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1); //Thickness wont apply to button I dont know why
        btn0.BorderBrush = brush; //This is also applied to button
```

Comment: The button template is probably setting the border thickness explicitly.

Comment: I think the suggested way might be to bind these properties to a view model and then alter that binded correlating property instead of directly working with the imperative code.

Answer (score 17):

The default border thickness for Buttons is 1 so nothing will change if you set it to 1.

[image]

To see a change just set it to something different:

```
button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 3);
```

[image]

Comment: But it does not look like button's border thickness is 1, I would say it looks like it's 3 or smth, thats reason why I want to set it up to 1, I will post screenshot later and you will see what I am talking about :)

Answer (score 6):

Since the default button template don't have Border property, More information you can visit: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28VS.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). 
So if you want a border around button you have to add your own style, Like:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

In above code all properties like: `BorderBrush`, `BorderThickness` and `Background` are hard coded and you can't set these property from code behind. if you want to do so you have to write style like:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
             <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Property=Background}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
             </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And apply this style like:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="btnNew" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle }" Width="200" Height="50" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

After that you can change those property of Border as your wish, For example:

```
btnNew.Background = Brushes.Black;
btnNew.BorderThickness = new Thickness(4, 5, 7, 9);
btnNew.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: The default button in WPF has a border property, no need to add it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: Definitely @91378246 , Button class has a property named `Border` , But I am talking about Template. `ContentPresenter` is the thing which is responsible for any content with in button and that `ContentPresenter` don't have `Border` so for change `Border` thickness first you have to add it and the easiest way is wrap `ContentPresenter` inside a `Border` and play with it like I did it above. There can be other way but This is what I found easy.