# Button border thickness doesnt change from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Background="LightGreen" Height="50" Width="70"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Button1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red
    Button1.BorderThickness = New Thickness(5)
End Sub
End Class
```

When you run the codes above you will see that;

Button1 border brush changes to red which is okey.

Button1 border thickness doesnt change to 5 which is not okey.

This issue is look like unsolved:

[Button border thickness from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616005/button-border-thickness-from-code-behind/38618280)

Comment: It works on my machine. It could be that the Template that is being used for the button does not respect the BorderThickness but that is a guess

Answer (score 0):

Like Erno de Weerd said in the comments it could be a template issue. I've been burned by this several times starting out.

[The answer to this question is very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136200/difference-between-style-and-controltemplate)

It talks about using the {TemplateBinding} expression when binding in a controls template